# Bootstrap: Make expanded input field overlap menu-items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've added an expanding input field in my Bootstrap `.navbar`, that only shows once the search button has been clicked. Right now the expanded input field pushes the menu-items to the left. When positioning `#search-form` absolute, the input field breaks out of on the right side of the container.

How can I make the search-form overlap the menu-times to the left?

**Example**:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#search-button, #search-icon").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#search-button, #search-form").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#search-form {
  display: none;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">This</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">and</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">That</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id="search-button" class="btn btn-link"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div id="search-form" class="form-group has-feedback">
              <div class="input-group">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="search"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Edit:**

Added screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How can I make the search-form overlap the menu-times to the left?

what you want to do?

Comment: @AjayMakwana I've added a screenshot to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

This did the job:

```
.nav>li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
}
```